# Laravel - One view for all possible errors

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

So I want to cover all posible and unexpected errors (like 401, 404, 500) with just one view. I want the same view to show up on all possible errors. I came up with a solution - to copy/paste the same code and just name the views with different error codes. But that seems stiff and wrong. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to achieve this effect is by modifying [Laravel's exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler).

Modify `App\Exceptions\Handler` to catch every error and return your shared custom error page.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Some customization may be required to fully meet exactly what & how you want data passed to your shared custom view.

Answer (score 3):

In the file **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** you can change what happens when an exception is thrown. In particular there's a `render` method in there that you can use to catch all the exceptions in an application.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // Handle your error here. Perhaps you can show a view
    // when a condition is met. Anything that isn't caught
    // here will be handled by Laravel with the
    // parent::render call below

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

The `parent::render($request, $e)` is where Laravel would normally show it's exception/oops page. So by overriding this method you can catch all application errors, including 404, 401 etc.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the error code to your view on the handler, and display the code on your page, use a switch to handle all the messages depending on the error code.

Answer (score -1):

You can create one unique view (default to 404 error), use try catch in your code to capture other errors and call to this view with parameters so you can change the 404 default error to other error.